# android 1.6 httpresponse doesn't include a location header

Tags: java, android, http-headers, location

i have an android 1.6 application that i'm trying to get the location header of a HTTP GET response. however, when i call getLastHeader("location") it returns null. i even go into the response variable via debugger and there is no location header sent. i need to do this on an arbitrary site, but using google for testing purposes still produces the mishap. i thought location was a default header to be read? does android 1.6 not read the location header? my code is as followed:

```
HttpClient httpClient = DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://google.com");
try
{
 HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
 if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
 {
  Header h = response.getLastHeader("location");
  String location = h.getValue();
 }
}
```

help is greatly appreciated :) i'm either looking for a solution to get the location or an explanation why i'm not getting it :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), Point 14.30

> The Location response-header field is
>   used to redirect the recipient to a
>   location other than the Request-URI
>   for completion of the request or
>   identification of a new resource. For
>   201 (Created) responses, the Location
>   is that of the new resource which was
>   created by the request. For 3xx
>   responses, the location SHOULD
>   indicate the server's preferred URI
>   for automatic redirection to the
>   resource. The field value consists of
>   a single absolute URI.

So if your response status is 200, the Location header should not be set, hence the null you have.

You can also check by using Firebug to check the header returned.

Comment: how should I implement then in order to get the redirected url ?